# Bitcore install errors

Tags: windows, node.js, bitcoin

I am trying to install the [Bitcore](http://bitcore.io/) module for node on Windows 7 and am running into a few errors. Tried for quite a while to fix this but am not getting anywhere. Any pointers would be really great.

```
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ruglify/-/ruglify-1.0.0.tgz
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/rfile/-/rfile-1.0.0.tgz
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/process
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/process/-/process-0.6.0.tgz
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/base64-js
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ieee754
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/readable-stream
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/readable-stream/-/readable-stream-1.1.13
    -1.tgz
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/typedarray
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/lexical-scope
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/esprima-fb
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/through
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/esprima-fb/-/esprima-fb-3001.0001.0000-d
    ev-harmony-fb.tgz
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ruglify/-/ruglify-1.0.0.tgz
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/process/-/process-0.5.2.tgz
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/process/-/process-0.6.0.tgz
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/readable-stream/-/readable-stream-1.1.13
    -1.tgz
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/indexof
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/esrefactor
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/pako
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/detective
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/Base64
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/base64-js
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ieee754
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/indexof/-/indexof-0.0.1.tgz
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch/-/minimatch-0.3.0.tgz
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/Base64/-/Base64-0.2.1.tgz
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/pako/-/pako-0.2.1.tgz
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lexical-scope/-/lexical-scope-1.1.0.tgz
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/object-keys
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/isarray
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/core-util-is
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/typedarray/-/typedarray-0.0.6.tgz
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/base64-js/-/base64-js-0.0.6.tgz
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ieee754/-/ieee754-1.1.3.tgz
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/esrefactor/-/esrefactor-0.1.0.tgz
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/detective/-/detective-3.1.0.tgz
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/string_decoder
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jsonparse
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/indexof/-/indexof-0.0.1.tgz
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch/-/minimatch-0.3.0.tgz
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/Base64/-/Base64-0.2.1.tgz
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/lexical-scope/-/lexical-scope-1.1.0.tgz
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/pako/-/pako-0.2.1.tgz
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/typedarray/-/typedarray-0.0.6.tgz
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/base64-js/-/base64-js-0.0.6.tgz
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ieee754/-/ieee754-1.1.3.tgz
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/esrefactor/-/esrefactor-0.1.0.tgz
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/detective/-/detective-3.1.0.tgz
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/isarray
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/isarray/-/isarray-0.0.1.tgz
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jsonparse
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/core-util-is
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/core-util-is/-/core-util-is-1.0.1.tgz
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/object-keys
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/string_decoder
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/string_decoder/-/string_decoder-0.10.25-
    1.tgz
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/object-keys/-/object-keys-0.4.0.tgz
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/isarray/-/isarray-0.0.1.tgz
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/core-util-is/-/core-util-is-1.0.1.tgz
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/object-keys/-/object-keys-0.4.0.tgz
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/string_decoder/-/string_decoder-0.10.25-
    1.tgz
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/callsite
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/resolve
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js/-/uglify-js-2.2.5.tgz
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js/-/uglify-js-2.2.5.tgz
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/escodegen
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/resolve
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sigmund
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/resolve/-/resolve-0.3.1.tgz
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/callsite
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/resolve/-/resolve-0.3.1.tgz
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/source-map
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-to-browserify
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/escodegen
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/escodegen/-/escodegen-1.1.0.tgz
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/sigmund
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cycle
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/request
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/pkginfo
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/stack-trace
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/async
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sigmund/-/sigmund-1.0.0.tgz
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache/-/lru-cache-2.5.0.tgz
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/escodegen/-/escodegen-1.1.0.tgz
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/sigmund/-/sigmund-1.0.0.tgz
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache/-/lru-cache-2.5.0.tgz
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-to-browserify
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/astw
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/source-map
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/request
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/request/-/request-2.9.203.tgz
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/cycle
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cycle/-/cycle-1.0.3.tgz
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/pkginfo
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/request/-/request-2.9.203.tgz
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/async
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/cycle/-/cycle-1.0.3.tgz
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/stack-trace
    npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat 'c:\Users\James\Desktop\BitcoinApp\node_modules\bi
    tcore\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\module-deps\node_modules\detective\no
    de_modules\escodegen\README.md'
    npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
    npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
    npm ERR!     

    npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
    npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
    ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "bitcore"
    npm ERR! cwd c:\Users\James\Desktop\BitcoinApp
    npm ERR! node -v v0.10.28
    npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
    npm ERR! path c:\Users\James\Desktop\BitcoinApp\node_modules\bitcore\node_module
    s\browserify\node_modules\module-deps\node_modules\detective\node_modules\escode
    gen\README.md
    npm ERR! fstream_path c:\Users\James\Desktop\BitcoinApp\node_modules\bitcore\nod
    e_modules\browserify\node_modules\module-deps\node_modules\detective\node_module
    s\escodegen\README.md
    npm ERR! fstream_type File
    npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
    npm ERR! code ENOENT
    npm ERR! errno 34
    npm ERR! fstream_stack C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\fst
    ream\lib\writer.js:284:26
    npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/pkginfo/-/pkginfo-0.2.3.tgz
    npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat 'c:\Users\James\Desktop\BitcoinApp\node_modules\bi
    tcore\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\module-deps\node_modules\detective\no
    de_modules\esprima-fb\README.md'
    npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
    npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
    npm ERR!     

    npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
    npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
    ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "bitcore"
    npm ERR! cwd c:\Users\James\Desktop\BitcoinApp
    npm ERR! node -v v0.10.28
    npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
    npm ERR! path c:\Users\James\Desktop\BitcoinApp\node_modules\bitcore\node_module
    s\browserify\node_modules\module-deps\node_modules\detective\node_modules\esprim
    a-fb\README.md
    npm ERR! fstream_path c:\Users\James\Desktop\BitcoinApp\node_modules\bitcore\nod
    e_modules\browserify\node_modules\module-deps\node_modules\detective\node_module
    s\esprima-fb\README.md
    npm ERR! fstream_type File
    npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
    npm ERR! code ENOENT
    npm ERR! errno 34
    npm ERR! fstream_stack C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\fst
    ream\lib\writer.js:284:26
    npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
    npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat 'c:\Users\James\Desktop\BitcoinApp\node_modules\bi
    tcore\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\umd\node_modules\uglify-js\node_modul
    es\source-map\Makefile.dryice.js'
    npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
    npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
    npm ERR!     

    npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
    npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
    ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "bitcore"
    npm ERR! cwd c:\Users\James\Desktop\BitcoinApp
    npm ERR! node -v v0.10.28
    npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
    npm ERR! path c:\Users\James\Desktop\BitcoinApp\node_modules\bitcore\node_module
    s\browserify\node_modules\umd\node_modules\uglify-js\node_modules\source-map\Mak
    efile.dryice.js
    npm ERR! fstream_path c:\Users\James\Desktop\BitcoinApp\node_modules\bitcore\nod
    e_modules\browserify\node_modules\umd\node_modules\uglify-js\node_modules\source
    -map\Makefile.dryice.js
    npm ERR! fstream_type File
    npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
    npm ERR! code ENOENT
    npm ERR! errno 34
    npm ERR! fstream_stack C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\fst
    ream\lib\writer.js:284:26
    npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/astw
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/async/-/async-0.1.22.tgz
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/stack-trace/-/stack-trace-0.0.9.tgz
    npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EPERM, unlink 'c:\Users\James\Desktop\Bitcoin
    App\node_modules\bitcore\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\browserify-zlib\no
    de_modules\pako\dist\pako_deflate.js'
    npm ERR! error rolling back  bitcore@0.1.21 { [Error: EPERM, unlink 'c:\Users\Ja
    mes\Desktop\BitcoinApp\node_modules\bitcore\node_modules\browserify\node_modules
    \browserify-zlib\node_modules\pako\dist\pako_deflate.js']
    npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 50,
    npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EPERM',
    npm ERR! error rolling back   path: 'c:\\Users\\James\\Desktop\\BitcoinApp\\node
    _modules\\bitcore\\node_modules\\browserify\\node_modules\\browserify-zlib\\node
    _modules\\pako\\dist\\pako_deflate.js' }
    npm ERR! bignum@0.6.2 install: `node-gyp configure build`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the bignum@0.6.2 install script.
    npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the bignum package,
    npm ERR! not with npm itself.
    npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
    npm ERR!     node-gyp configure build
    npm ERR! You can get their info via:
    npm ERR!     npm owner ls bignum
    npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
    npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
    ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "bitcore"
    npm ERR! cwd c:\Users\James\Desktop\BitcoinApp
    npm ERR! node -v v0.10.28
    npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/astw/-/astw-1.1.0.tgz
    npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat 'c:\Users\James\Desktop\BitcoinApp\node_modules\bi
    tcore\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\umd\node_modules\ruglify\node_modules
    \uglify-js\lib\parse.js'
    npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
    npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
    npm ERR!     

    npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
    npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
    ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "bitcore"
    npm ERR! cwd c:\Users\James\Desktop\BitcoinApp
    npm ERR! node -v v0.10.28
    npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
    npm ERR! path c:\Users\James\Desktop\BitcoinApp\node_modules\bitcore\node_module
    s\browserify\node_modules\umd\node_modules\ruglify\node_modules\uglify-js\lib\pa
    rse.js
    npm ERR! fstream_path c:\Users\James\Desktop\BitcoinApp\node_modules\bitcore\nod
    e_modules\browserify\node_modules\umd\node_modules\ruglify\node_modules\uglify-j
    s\lib\parse.js
    npm ERR! fstream_type File
    npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
    npm ERR! code ENOENT
    npm ERR! errno 34
    npm ERR! fstream_stack C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\fst
    ream\lib\writer.js:284:26
    npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
    npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat 'c:\Users\James\Desktop\BitcoinApp\node_modules\bi
    tcore\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\browserify-zlib\node_modules\pako\dis
    t\pako_deflate.js'
    npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
    npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
    npm ERR!     

    npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
    npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
    ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "bitcore"
    npm ERR! cwd c:\Users\James\Desktop\BitcoinApp
    npm ERR! node -v v0.10.28
    npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
    npm ERR! path c:\Users\James\Desktop\BitcoinApp\node_modules\bitcore\node_module
    s\browserify\node_modules\browserify-zlib\node_modules\pako\dist\pako_deflate.js

    npm ERR! fstream_path c:\Users\James\Desktop\BitcoinApp\node_modules\bitcore\nod
    e_modules\browserify\node_modules\browserify-zlib\node_modules\pako\dist\pako_de
    flate.js
    npm ERR! fstream_type File
    npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
    npm ERR! code ENOENT
    npm ERR! errno 34
    npm ERR! fstream_stack C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\fst
    ream\lib\writer.js:284:26
    npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/pkginfo/-/pkginfo-0.2.3.tgz
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/async/-/async-0.1.22.tgz
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/stack-trace/-/stack-trace-0.0.9.tgz
    npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/astw/-/astw-1.1.0.tgz
    npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EPERM, rmdir 'c:\Users\James\Desktop\BitcoinA
    pp\node_modules\bitcore\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\umd\node_modules\rf
    ile\node_modules\resolve'
    npm ERR! error rolling back  umd@2.0.0 { [Error: EPERM, rmdir 'c:\Users\James\De
    sktop\BitcoinApp\node_modules\bitcore\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\umd\n
    ode_modules\rfile\node_modules\resolve']
    npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 50,
    npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EPERM',
    npm ERR! error rolling back   path: 'c:\\Users\\James\\Desktop\\BitcoinApp\\node
    _modules\\bitcore\\node_modules\\browserify\\node_modules\\umd\\node_modules\\rf
    ile\\node_modules\\resolve' }
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
    npm ERR!     c:\Users\James\Desktop\BitcoinApp\npm-debug.log
    npm ERR! not ok code 0

    c:\Users\James\Desktop\BitcoinApp>
```

npm-debug.log

```
    15435 error Error: ENOENT, lstat 'c:\Users\James\Desktop\BitcoinApp\node_modules\bitcore\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\module-deps\node_modules\detective\node_modules\escodegen\README.md'
    15436 error If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
    15436 error including the npm and node versions, at:
    15436 error     
    15437 error System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
    15438 error command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "bitcore"
    15439 error cwd c:\Users\James\Desktop\BitcoinApp
    15440 error node -v v0.10.28
    15441 error npm -v 1.4.9
    15442 error path c:\Users\James\Desktop\BitcoinApp\node_modules\bitcore\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\module-deps\node_modules\detective\node_modules\escodegen\README.md
    15443 error fstream_path c:\Users\James\Desktop\BitcoinApp\node_modules\bitcore\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\module-deps\node_modules\detective\node_modules\escodegen\README.md
    15444 error fstream_type File
    15445 error fstream_class FileWriter
    15446 error code ENOENT
    15447 error errno 34
    15448 error fstream_stack C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\fstream\lib\writer.js:284:26
    15448 error fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
    15449 verbose exit [ 34, true ]
```